# How can EC2 instance Access Local machine

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-kafka

I have a single Kafka broker running in my local mac port 9092 and a topic produced in my local mac as well. I wanted to run a consumer in EC2 to consume my local mac broker topic. I have enabled inbound and outbound access to TCP port 9092 for all IP (0.0.0.0/0) in the EC2 security group.

When I run a consumer command in EC2:

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server <localmac IP>:9092 --topic <topicname> --from-beginning
```

I get connect timeout error(**org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException:**).

What other outbound/inbound rules in EC2 security group Am I missing here for EC2 to access the local mac address.

Comment: How is your "local mac" connected to the Internet? Is it behind a router? Does it have a public IP address? It it accessible from the Internet? (If it is behind a router, you'll often need to configure Port Forwarding on the router.) Have you managed to have any other computer connect to the "local mac"?

Comment: you should verify that the EC2 can access the internet without problem. Then, verify that your Mac is not blocking your request on that specific port.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure an advertised listener on your broker for the EC2 consumer to connect to. At the moment you're connecting to the broker on the remote IP of your machine but the broker returns the local IP to the consumer for it to continue its requests to.

Ref: https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/